# How do you make JQuery WebTicket full-screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, the webticket only goes to about a little over 2/5ths of the screen, I'm trying to figure out how I can stretch the width out so that it covers the entire screen's width.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wf43X/56/light/

Javascript:

```
/*!
 * webTicker 1.3
 * Examples and documentation at: 
 * http://jonmifsud.com
 * 2011 Jonathan Mifsud
 * Version: 1.2 (26-JUNE-2011)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Requires:
 * jQuery v1.4.2 or later
 * 
 */
(function($) {

    var globalSettings = new Array();

    var methods = {
        init: function(settings) { // THIS 
            settings = jQuery.extend({
                travelocity: 0.05,
                direction: 1,
                moving: true
            }, settings);
            globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')] = settings;
            return this.each(function() {
                var $strip = jQuery(this);
                $strip.addClass("newsticker")
                var stripWidth = 0;
                var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
                $mask.after("<span class='tickeroverlay-left'>&nbsp;</span><span class='tickeroverlay-right'>&nbsp;</span>")
                var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
                $strip.find("li").each(function(i) {
                    stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true);
                });
                $strip.width(stripWidth + 200); //20 used for ie9 fix                    


                function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) {
                    if (settings.direction == 1) $strip.animate({
                        left: '-=' + spazio
                    }, tempo, "linear", function() {
                        $strip.children().last().after($strip.children().first());
                        var first = $strip.children().first();
                        var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                        var defTiming = width / settings.travelocity;
                        //$strip.css("left", left);
                        $strip.css("left", '0');
                        scrollnews(width, defTiming);
                    });
                    else $strip.animate({
                        right: '-=' + spazio
                    }, tempo, "linear", function() {
                        $strip.children().last().after($strip.children().first());
                        var first = $strip.children().first();
                        var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                        var defTiming = width / settings.travelocity;
                        //$strip.css("left", left);
                        $strip.css("right", '0');
                        scrollnews(width, defTiming);
                    });
                }

                var first = $strip.children().first();
                var travel = first.outerWidth(true);
                var timing = travel / settings.travelocity;
                scrollnews(travel, timing);
                $strip.hover(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop();
                }, function() {
                    if (globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')].moving) {
                        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                        var first = $strip.children().first();
                        var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                        var residualSpace;
                        if (settings.direction == 1) residualSpace = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('left').replace('px', '')) + width;
                        else residualSpace = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('right').replace('px', '')) + width;
                        var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
                        scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        stop: function() {
            if (globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')].moving) {
                globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')].moving = false;
                return this.each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop();
                });
            }
        },
        cont: function() { // GOOD     
            if (!(globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')].moving)) {
                globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')].moving = true;
                var settings = globalSettings[jQuery(this).attr('id')];
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $strip = jQuery(this);

                    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) {
                        if (settings.direction == 1) $strip.animate({
                            left: '-=' + spazio
                        }, tempo, "linear", function() {
                            $strip.children().last().after($strip.children().first());
                            var first = $strip.children().first();
                            var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                            var defTiming = width / settings.travelocity;
                            //$strip.css("left", left);
                            $strip.css("left", '0');
                            scrollnews(width, defTiming);
                        });
                        else $strip.animate({
                            right: '-=' + spazio
                        }, tempo, "linear", function() {
                            $strip.children().last().after($strip.children().first());
                            var first = $strip.children().first();
                            var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                            var defTiming = width / settings.travelocity;
                            //$strip.css("left", left);
                            $strip.css("right", '0');
                            scrollnews(width, defTiming);
                        });

                    }
                    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                    var first = $strip.children().first();
                    var width = first.outerWidth(true);
                    var residualSpace;
                    if (settings.direction == 1) residualSpace = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('left').replace('px', '')) + width;
                    else residualSpace = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('right').replace('px', '')) + width;
                    var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
                    scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);

                });
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.webTicker = function(method) {

        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.webTicker');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);

jQuery('#webticker').webTicker()
```

CSS:

```
.tickercontainer { /* the outer div with the black border */
width: 500px;
height: 27px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.tickercontainer .mask { /* that serves as a mask. so you get a sort of padding both left and right */
position: relative;
top: 8px;
height: 18px;
/*width: 718px;*/
overflow: hidden;
}
ul.newsticker { /* that's your list */
position: relative;
/*left: 750px;*/
font: bold 10px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul.newsticker li {
float: left; /* important: display inline gives incorrect results when you check for elem's width */
margin: 0;
padding-right: 15px;
/*background: #fff;*/
}
```

Thanks,
Dan